# Наследование в Java (вопрос от новичка)

Tags: java

Не могу понять, почему код не работает.

```
public class Exp{
  String word;
  Exp(String name){
    word = name;
  }
  public void method(){
    System.out.println(word);
  }
}

public class A{
  A(String name){
    Exp ex = new Exp(name);
  }
}

public class B extends A{
  B(){
    super("Hello World!");
  }
  public void textMethod(){
    ex.method();
  }
}
```

Выдает ошибку javac B.java
B.java:6: error: cannot find symbol ex.method();

Как я понимаю, класс B должен наследовать объект ex с класса A. Не могли бы подсказать почему код не работает и как сделать так, чтобы он заработал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас `ex` - локальная переменная в конструкторе `A`.

```
public class A{
  protected Exp ex;
  A(String name) {
    ex = new Exp(name);
  }
}
```